# PHP Mailer. Clicking send downloads the php script but does not send mail

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, phpmailer

I am following [a tutorial](http://www.tudor-anghelina.com/2013/09/how-to-create-php-bootstrap-3-contact.html) on how to implement a simple Bootstrap contact form with a PhP mailer script.

However when I click Send Message, my contact form downloads the PHP script rather than sending the email. What am I doing wrong?

Bootstrap - HTML

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="http://location_of_my_web_app/php/mailer.php" class="form-horizontal" role="form">

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Your Name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Your Email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputSubject" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Subject</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSubject" name="inputSubject" placeholder="Subject Message">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="inputMessage" name="inputMessage" placeholder="Your message..."></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <center>
        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
        </div>
    </center>
    </div> 
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail = "my_address@gmail.com";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$name = check_input($_POST['inputName'], "Your Name");
$email = check_input($_POST['inputEmail'], "Your E-mail Address");
$subject = check_input($_POST['inputSubject'], "Message Subject");
$message = check_input($_POST['inputMessage'], "Your Message");

/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("Invalid e-mail address");
}
/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */

$subject = "Someone has sent you a message";

$message = "

Someone has sent you a message using your contac form:

Name: $name
Email: $email
Subject: $subject

Message:
$message

";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: http://location_of_my_thank_you_page/Static/contact_thankyou.html');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>
<body>

<p>Please correct the following error:</p>
<strong><?php echo $myError; ?></strong>
<p>Hit the back button and try again</p>

</body>
</html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: make sure the file extension is 'php', check the mime-types and htacces setup

Comment: *"my contact form downloads the PHP script rather than sending the email"* --- Sounds like PHP is either not installed/running or not properly configured. Do up a `test.php` file with `<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>` and see if it does the same thing. If it does (want to download), then there's your problem. Also make sure you're using `.php` as an extension, and not `.html`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Looks like you are right. Unfortunately when I try to install PHP via sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 I am told I am not a sodoer. I will likely have to wait till after the long weekend. I would be happy accept your comment if you format it as an answer.

Comment: Ok, as per your request, I posted it below. @Deepend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"my contact form downloads the PHP script rather than sending the email"*

It sounds like PHP is either not installed/running or not properly configured.

I suggest that you create a file called `test.php` file with `<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>` inside it and see if it does the same thing.

If it still wants to appear like it wants to download, then there's the problem; PHP is not installed or not properly configured and isn't parsing PHP as it normally should.

Create another file and place `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and it should show you the server's information.